# Laravel 5: validation of two fields simultaneously with form request

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I need to simultaneously validate two fields of a form with form request. The fields are time and weekday, coming from a table named calendar, and must be entered into the database in another table called schedule.

If the time and weekday are true in the table called calendar, the validation should stop the insertion of this data into the table called schedule.

Can someone help? thanks.

Comment: Is the question really about validation or insertion? If you want to prevent form submission in a specific scenario, then validation used. But, as far as I understood your question, it's whether to store the data in another table or not.

Comment: What have you tried? Have are you trying to achieve this at the moment?